# What does "render @collection" do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I'm trying to learn Rails better by looking at example applications, and while looking at [this line of the source of railscasts.com](http://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/master/app/views/episodes/index.html.erb#L14), I noticed it does this:

```
<div class="episodes">
    <%= render @episodes %>
  </div>
```

What exactly is going on here? Why isn't this documented on the render function? Or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is shorthand for

`render :partial => "episode", :collection => @episodes`

The form above is documented in the [Rails API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) under `render (ActionController::Base)`. The shorthand form is not documented as far as I can see except in the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rails.info/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: there's a blurb about this in Ruby on Rails 2.3 Release Notes, 6.2 Smart Rendering of Partials http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#smart-rendering-of-partials

Comment: Thanks zetetic. And thanks Corey, at least someone found it. I hate knowing that there is undocumented stuff out there.

Answer (score 6):

This is a handy shortcut for doing

```
<%= render :partial => "episode", :collection => @episodes %>
```

which is another way of doing

```
<% for episode in @episodes do %>
  <%= render :partial => "episode", :locals => { :episode => episode }
<% end %>
```

which is pretty obvious in what it does :)

Hope that makes sense :)

btw it's really surprising I couldn't find the docs for this too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new shortcut:

```
<%= render @episodes %>

# equivalent to
<%= render :partial => 'episode', :collection => @episodes %>
```

You can also do shortcuts with single items

```
<%= render 'comment', comment => @comment  %>

# equivalent to
<%= render :partial => 'comment', :locals => {:comment => @comment} %>
```