# Nokogiri image grabbing from a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

I'm trying to get images for an index page.  I'd like to have Nokogiri go to each design's page, grab the first image in the body, and give me those images for use in the partial.  In the console, this works great.  In my actual view, it times out.

_design.html.haml

```
- doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{design_url(design)}"))
%li.well.blur{style: "background-image: url(#{doc.at_css('.well img')['src']})"}
```

See what I'm trying to do?  In the index, I'm doing a standard `= render @designs`, and thinking that, as it loops through each design, it will run the Nokogiri command, assign the image url from each variable, change, and carry on.

In the console:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://localhost:3000/designs/1"))
doc.at_css('.well img')['src']
```

quickly returns:

```
=> "http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~olivetoj2/blah.jpg"
```

I'm missing something, obviously.  Any ideas?  Can I even define a variable in the view??  I don't see where else I could declare it.

---

UPDATE:

I tried moving the logic to the model:

design.rb:

```
def first_image
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("`http://localhost:3000/designs/1`"))
  doc.at_css('.well img')['src']  
end
```

Hard-coded the URL for testing purposes, then, in the partial, changed to:

```
%li.well.blur{style: "background-image: url(#{design.first_image})"}
```

But I had the same problem though, time out.

---

UPDATE:

I kept the logic in the model, and even added a column for the info, then took the call out of the design partial all together. Now, I call `@design.first_image` in the `create action` and the `update action`.

design.rb:

```
def first_image
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://localhost:3000/designs/#{self.id}"))
  self.update_attribute(:photo_url, doc.at_css('.well img')['src'])
end
```

Same issue, timeout.  It works fine in the console though.  I just don't get it.

Comment: how are you passing the `design` variable to your partial?

Comment: relying on the magic of rails for this one.  Controller is `designs_controller.rb`, Model is `design.rb`, so I have the `_design.html.haml` partial in `views/designs`.

Comment: Great idea passing this to the controller, are you able to use the design variable in your new partial?

Comment: updated... still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you load a `partial` you will have to pass the used parameters manually. In your case it would be something like:

```
render :partial => 'designs/design', :locals => { :design => design }
                       |        |                    |         |
                   view folder  |     variable used in partial |
                                |                              |
                          partial name               current name of variable
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567732/what-does-render-collection-do - that'll explain the shortcut better than I can, I suppose.  My problem isn't that I don't have access to the `design` variable, but the `doc` variable in the first part of my question.  The real question is, why does nokogiri work fine in the console, and not in the view?